# InAppBrowser Allow-Navigation ONLY MY DOMAIN when it is already open

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, webview, inappbrowser

I know there are a thousand threads talking about this topic, but it is that, really reading them and executing what they say, I can not find the key. And .. I have read and already tried many.

My problem is the following. I'm using InAppBrowser module `(InAppBrowser from @ ionic-native / in-app-browser / ngx)`

I am creating the following code.

```
constructor (private iab: InAppBrowser, private platform: Platform) {
    this.iab.create ('http://www.myweb.com/app', '_blank', 'EnableViewPortScale = yes, location = no, hidenavigationbuttons = yes, enableViewportScale = yes, hideurlbar = yes, zoom = no, mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = yes');
  }
```

This opens a browser inside my application until here, everything is correct. But, once I'm in, if I start navigating and I leave my domain, I would like it not to be possible.
But once the browser is opened it is as if my application was not responsible for the domains where I browse.

Still having in my config.xml the rules of access origin, allow-navigation and allow-intent I only target my domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks post @andreszs i found the solution.

The real problem, was that at least USING IONIC NATIVE InAppBrowser. Events like browser.on ('loadstart') are not loaded if the "Location" option is not active. Then, using angular@typescript code with ionic I was able to call the bases functions of cordova inappbrowser.

```
this.browser = this.iab.create(myurl, '_blank', 'location=yes');

this.browser.on('loadstart').subscribe(event => {
    if(event.url.search(notMYurl) == -1) {
         this.browser.close();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really must implement IAB like this, you can prevent the loading of unauthorized URLs by using the `loadstart` event listener as explained [in this article](https://www.andreszsogon.com/how-to-close-inappbrowser-window-in-cordova-by-itself/), then use the `close` method to exit it whenever the navigated URL is undesirable. You could also have your initial domain reloaded again. (Jump to ***Using the loadstart event to close the InAppBrowser*** in the linked article)

Anyway, you should try to avoid the **InAppBrowser** usage whenever possible.

Comment: If I do not use IAB, what pluggin, or what I use, in order to create an application that will only use the browser, since it is a WebView. I know there is a WebView native of cordova (or ionic, I do not remember). But I hardly find documentation

Comment: Meaby my bad, becouse i didnt type im using IONIC. The function "open" is deprecated i used your article's code. But didnt work just for Ionic >.<