# Hide Location toolbar from IONIC Native InAppBrowser

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, webview, inappbrowser

Reading the [cordova documentation inappbrowser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser#cordovainappbrowseropen) I can not find a way to hide the Location Toolbar (ALWAYS AND WHEN it has "location = yes") and just for Android, becouse we can use "toolbar=no" on IOs.

Why the need to have active "location = yes"? You can put "no" and it does not appear anymore.

As I comment in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57069539/8900937), I need the activated option to be able to make use of the functions of ionic native IAB

Options i use:

```
location=yes,
EnableViewPortScale=yes,
hidenavigationbuttons=yes,
enableViewportScale=yes,
hideurlbar=yes,
zoom=no,
mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction=yes,
```

[image]

As we can see in the image, the toolbar still appears at the top.

Any option that has been overlooked?
Is it possible to remove it with CSS, if so, does it have any Class or ID to call, or should I touch it with pure code?

Comment: `location=no` in your options

Comment: This is on android or where?

Comment: Yes, is IONIC and platform android

Answer (score 3):

According to

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/

set `toolbar=no`

```
var dataref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, target, options)<--------pass to this place
```

> toolbar: set to yes or no to turn the toolbar on or off for the
>   InAppBrowser (defaults to yes)

Comment: Thats just por IOs

Answer (score 2):

for **ios** to implement use this code if you are viewing the .html or .pdf file it hide the address bar call this function `getFileExtension` from your code.

```
function getFileExtension(filename) {
           var fileName = filename.split('.').pop();
           if (fileName == 'pdf')
           {
               viewLinkpdf(filename)
           }
           else 
           {
               viewLink(filename)
           }
       }
       function viewLink(filepath) {
            var url = (filepath.match('http')) ? filepath : 'http://' + filepath;
            var win = window.open( url, "_blank", "location=no" );
       }

function viewLinkpdf(filepath) {
           var url = (filepath.match('http')) ? filepath : 'http://' + filepath;
            window.open(encodeURI('https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url='+url), '_blank', 'location=no,EnableViewPortScale=yes');
       }
```

similar like for **android** but very minor changes are there

```
function viewLinkpdf(filepath) {
        var url = (filepath.match('http')) ? filepath : 'http://' + filepath;
        window.open(encodeURI('https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url='+url), '_blank', 'location=no,EnableViewPortScale=yes');
    }
    function getFileExtension(filename) {
        var fileName = filename.split('.').pop();
        if (fileName == 'pdf')
        {
            viewLinkpdf(filename)
        }
        else 
        {
            viewLink(filename)
        }
    }
    function viewLink(filepath) {
        var url = (filepath.match('http')) ? filepath : 'http://' + filepath;
        var options = {
            location: 'no',
            clearcache: 'yes',
            toolbar: 'no'
        };
        $cordovaInAppBrowser.open(url, '_blank', options)
        .then(function (event) {
            // success
        })
        .catch(function (event) {
            // error
        });
    }
```

i place both the code here might be its repeated catch it which you want. I hope this will help you.